# What is a good beginner's guide for MYSQL Partitioning?

Tags: mysql

Including...how to set up the partition, how to determine which partition to talk to...etc.
I know replication but am new to partitioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Improving Database Performance with Partitioning**
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good start: [MySQL Partitioning Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html)

Also, I haven't watched this one specifically, but the presentations by the Pythian group are usually pretty good.  Reading a manual may be more efficient, but as an alternative this video will teach you quite a bit about partitioning in MySQL.

[Partitioning in MySQL 5.1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvN9XI-FraI)